# How to show all months with dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I want to show all months , in a plot, created with dygraphs and JavaScript.
Now, the plot show only: Apr 2012, Jul 2012, Oct 2012

My values:

```
X,Y,Z
    2012/01/10,0,3
    2012/02/10,2,6
    2012/03/10,4,8
    2012/04/10,6,9
    2012/05/10,8,9
    2012/06/10,10,8
    2012/07/10,12,6
    2012/08/10,14,3
    2012/09/10,23,7
    2012/10/10,18,8
    2012/11/10,17,4
    2012/12/18,14,7
```

The code is here: [Edit fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h1z72s0/)

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs tries to choose a set of x-axis labels appropriate for the range of your data and the width of the chart. If you don't like its choice, you can override it with a [custom ticker](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#ticker).

In your case, to force monthly ticks, you might do this ([full fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncyaq5L6/)):

```js
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
      ticker: function(min, max, pixels, opts) {
        return Dygraph.getDateAxis(min, max, Dygraph.Granularity.MONTHLY, opts, this);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Be aware, though, that this might produce results that look bad. For your sample data and the default chart width, monthly ticks produce too many labels and they overlap one another:

[image: Chart with crowded x-axis labels]

Comment: your example doesn't include January. Is there a way to include it?

Comment: dygraphs places month ticks on the first of the month. The chart's minimum x value is Jan 10th, so the January label would be off the left edge. If you expand the range (via `dateWindow`) then you'll get a January tick.

Comment: so dateWindow expects a unix time stamp for january 1st 2012? for example, dateWindow: [1325376000, 'auto]?